# imap and the r operation

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

I write in English and Swedish in vim and have the lines below in my `.vimrc` to switch to and from a pseudo-Swedish keyboard layout. Basically some keys are remapped with `inoremmap` when doing `<Leader>s` to output Swedish characters, and characters that are masked by this are reached by hitting the key twice. `<Leader>e` undoes these mappings to return to English typing. This all works fine except for with the `r` operation. For example, when the Swedish mappings are in effect, `r[` does not change the letter to `å`, but to `[`. How can I make these mappings also affect the `r` operation?

Note that I do not want to use the OS's keyboard switch since this would effect operations in normal mode.

```
" Switch to Swedish
function! SweType()
  set spelllang=sv
  inoremap ; ö
  inoremap ;; ;
  inoremap : Ö
  inoremap :: :
  inoremap [ å
  inoremap { Å
  inoremap ' ä
  inoremap '' '
  inoremap " Ä
  inoremap "" "
  inoremap [[ [
  inoremap {{ {
endfunction
nmap <Leader>s :<C-U>call SweType()<CR>


" Switch to English
function! EngType()
  set spelllang=en_us
  inoremap ; ;
  iunmap ;;
  inoremap : :
  iunmap ::
  inoremap [ [
  iunmap [[
  inoremap { {
  iunmap {{
  inoremap ' '
  iunmap ''
  inoremap " "
  iunmap ""
endfunction
nmap <Leader>e :<C-U>call EngType()<CR>
```

Comment: This might help: `:help 'langmap'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to remap the whole sequence of keys in normal mode :

```
nnoremap r[ rå
```

Edited the answer, as I'm not sure in which mode we are when we hit `r`. Maybe a sub mode of insert mode that is left as soon as another key is pressed.

Comment: Isn't the mode your in after pressing `r` called operator pending mode or so?

Comment: I don't know in which mode we are when we hit `r` but as far I as I know there's no mapping for it (inoremap, vnoremap, cnoremap... have no effect). As for the operator pending mode, I think it's something else. When you hit the key of an operator (`d` to delete, `c` to cut, `s` to substitute etc.), vim waits for a movement to know on which characters it must act. I think that the term operator pending mode refers to that moment. But maybe I misunderstood the concept.

Comment: The text that is between your cursor and the position you reach after you give a movement could be considered as an object, on which the operator acts. You can define your own objects with the `onoremap` command. It's explained in more details here : http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html